# Sass::Importers to load from an alternative fallback folder

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to use a frontend project as a git submodule so i can use it as fallback import path if there is no file in the current project.

On the config.rb of the assets/sass/ folder, one simple line is required:

```
add_import_path "../../frontend/assets/sass/"
```

This way, if no file exists on the assets/sass/ folder structure it will try to find it on frontend/assets/sass/ folder.

This works but every `@import` tries to load relatively to the file where the `@import` is. I'm thinking on developing a Sass Importer that first tries to load the same file from an "A" folder structure and if it doesn't exists tries to load from "B" folder structure.

So, if there is a "assets/sass/common/base/_!base.scss" with an

```
@import "fonts/fonts";
```

First it will try to load it from:

`assets/sass/common/base/fonts/_fonts.scss`

And if it doesn't exist it will try to loads from:

`frontend/assets/sass/common/base/fonts/_fonts.scss`

So the question is:

**Is possible to accomplish that with a Sass importer?**

Looking for documentation (http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Importers/Base.html) or examples i didn't found something like this but i think it is not a strange case. I'm not used writing Ruby code so i must confirm if it can be done before i try to write some code.

Comment: Have you found anything on that matter? I'd also be interested in importers, but I didn't find a lot of stuff about these...

Comment: No, i didn't. I think that simply is not a good aproach to the problem so i give up.

Comment: I ended up with the same conclusion :) I tried but got a lot of errors and understood why the feature is tagged _experimental_! Thank you very much for your answer!